Number of non-negative integer solutions of $[x/m]=[x/n]$, $m,n , (m-1)/(m-n)\in \mathbb{N}$
To find the number  of non-negative integer solutions of $$[x/m]=[x/n],
\quad m,n \in \mathbb{N}, m>n, \text{gcd}(m,n)=1 ~~~~(*)$$ where $[.]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function (GIF).
By the estimation of $[F]$ as: $F-1 <[F]\le F$, we get
$$x/m-1<[x/m]\le x/m ~\text{and}~x/n-1<[x/n]\le x/n$$
Combining these two we get a good estimate for $x$ as $$-\frac{mn}{m-n}< x< \frac{mn}{m-n}$$
For the solutions of (*), we find that $n$ becomes the last term of an A.P with first term as $1$ and common difference as $(m-n)$. $$T_N=n=1+(N-1)(m-n) \implies N=\frac{m-1}{m-n}$$
then the number of non-negative integer solutions become the sum of this A.P of $N$ terms as
$$S_N=\frac{N(n+1)}{2}. ~~~~~~(**)$$
We have verified this for several cases of $(m,n)$ pairs as $(3,2), (6,5), (11,9),....(101,99).$
The question:
Our result $(**)$ is restricted to the cases where $N$ is whole number? What could be its generalization? Any comment is welcome.
EDIT(Examples):
(i) The number of non-negative solutions of $[x/6]=[x/5]$ are 5+4+3+2+1=15.
(ii) The number of non-negative solutions of $[x/11]=[x/9]$ are 9+7+5+3+1=25.
(iii) The number of non-negative solutions of $[x/99]=[x/101]$ are
99+97+95+93+.....+3+1=2500.
(iv) The number of non-negative solutions of $[x/11]=[x/6]$ are 6+1=7
In the case of:
How many positive integer solutions exist for $[\frac{x}{19}]=[\frac{x}{20}]$, where $[x]$ denotes the Greatest integer function
we get $$N=(20-1)/(20-19)=19, S_N= \frac{19\cdot 20}{2}=190.$$

I mean, it is true for all $m,n$ when $0\neq x<1.$ How does that relate to your statement about the arithmetic progression? Can you elaborate on the claim starting with "We find..." It doesn't appear to be true when $n=4,m=2,$

The core case is when $n=m+1.$ If it is true for any $n,m$ it is also true for $n',m'$ for any $m\leq m'\leq n'\leq n.$

(Whoops, my last comment reversed which variable was greater.)

@Thomas Andrews We have discussed the cases where gcd(m, n) =1.

In my Edit I have given examples now, please see.

So, are you seeing that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$ then $n=1+(N-1)(m-n),$ for some $N?$ This isn't true. $n=5,m=11$ is a counterexample.

Yes, our result required N to be a  whole number.. It is not general enough.
